# sharepoint 2013 number of viewes per listiem

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

Is it possible in Sharepoint 2013 to get the number of views per a listitem or a document out of the box, usage: render the views on a display form.

Answer (score -2):

There are 2 options to find number of hits for a page or a document

1. you ccan see that in the web/site analytics report
2. you can include a column "No. Of Views" on the library where the document /Page is stored

list items doesnt have number of views column

Regards
Arjun

Comment: thank you, create a column "No. Of Views", but how do you suggest to fill that column with data, on what basis.

Comment: There is already a column says "No of Views" plese click on Modify Columns on the list and check

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but I can't find a column with a name of "No. Of Views". Nor I can add an existing one from the site.

Comment: What do you have? a library or a list?

Comment: I have a document library.